# How can I realize subscribing to subtopics

Tags: ros, subscribe, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a message that consists of two (or more) submessages:

my_msgs/VehicleData:
sensor_msgs::NavSatFix gps
gps_msgs::GPSFix gps_fix

When I publish the message as /vehicle I can afterwards use these three commands:

$ rostopic echo /vehicle<br>
$ rostopic echo /vehicle/gps
$ rostopic echo /vehicle/gps_fix

All the commands return the specific submsgs.
When I now use the rqt_marble_plugin it doesn't display the /vehicle/gps submessage. Internally this program searches for NavSatFix topics but it doesn't find this one.

Can I somehow fix this?

I would like to be able to publish this VehicleData msg and subscribe either to the whole topic or to subtopics.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187014/how-can-i-realize-subscribing-to-subtopics/) by [wepmaschda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19777/wepmaschda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK there is not automatic way to do this. The `subtopic` concept does not really exist in ROS. Every node subscribes to topics and has to take care of accessing the composing messages itself. The `rostopic` tool works some magic to allow echoing only part of a message like in your example.

However, you might be able to use rostopic to republish the NavSatFix messages on a different topic (see the comment to this answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/58995/is-there-a-way-to-recompose-messages-from-command-line/?answer=59004#post-id-59004)

```
rostopic echo /vehicle/gps | rostopic pub /vehicle_gps_only sensor_msgs/NavSatFix
```

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wepmaschda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19777/wepmaschda/) on 2014-07-28**:
Thanks for the reply. I will for now just publish both topics in my node, the concatenated one and all the single ones.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-28**:
Yes, if you can change the implementation of your node, adding multiple publishers is the simplest option it seems.